# Sending e-mails from java

Tags: java, api, sendmail

I have a problem with sending e-mail from Java, when I'm using Java mail Authentification. I can't figure out way I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 530 Access denied
```

I will display below the entire code. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Please note that before adding authentication everything worked fine.
Also, do you know if it is possible to send emails between 2 different domain(eg. gmail to yahoo)?

```
// LoginDemo.java

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.Properties;

//import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
//import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

class Popup extends JFrame 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel label;
    JPanel panel;
    Popup(){
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("E-mail sent...");
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        label.setBounds(10,5, 100, 23);
        panel.add(label);

         add(panel);

         setTitle("Sending E-mails");
    }
}

class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public Authenticator() {
        String username = "andreeav@domain.com";
        String password = "password";
        authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Login extends 
JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton Send;
        JPanel panel;
        JLabel label1,label2, label3;
        final JTextField  text1,text2;
        JTextArea text3;
        String body_mail = " Dear Lavinia  \r\n\n 55544 - Andreea Deal (PERSONAL CARE PRODUCTS DIVISION) (CA)   (55544)(V.SOAP)AP needs your \n approval with the following details: \r\n Approval Cycle#: 1 \r\n Channel   Name: Andreea Channel \r\n Advertiser:Andreea Advertiser \r\n Agency:   ANDREEA AGENCY(P) LTD (CA) \r\n Period: 04/10/2012 - 04/30/2012 \r\n Amount: 436,000.00  \r\n   Expected Annual Spend: 0.00  \r\n Last Year Total Budget: 0.00 INR \r\n Last Year Discount: Minimum = 0.00, Maximum = 0.00 \r\n Comments: To approve or reject the proposal, please do not reply to sender e-mail   address. \n Please reply with your comments to the following e-mail address accordingly:  ";


    Login()
    {

        label3 = new JLabel();
        label3.setText("Created by andreeav on April 20th 2012");

        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("To:");
        text1 = new JTextField(50);

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setText("Subject:");
        text2 = new JTextField(50);

        text3 = new JTextArea(100, 100);

            text3.setText(body_mail);
        Send=new JButton("Send");

            panel=new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);

            label1.setBounds(10,5, 50, 23);
        panel.add(label1);
            text1.setBounds(60, 5, 550, 23);
        panel.add(text1);
        label2.setBounds(10,33,50,23);
        panel.add(label2);
        text2.setBounds(60, 33, 550, 23);
        panel.add(text2);
            text3.setBounds(10, 61, 600, 430);
        text3.setLineWrap(true);

        label3.setBounds(10, 513, 250, 23);
            panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(text3);

        Send.setBounds(520, 513, 90, 23);

        panel.add(Send);
        add(panel);
            Send.addActionListener(this);
            setTitle("Sending E-mails");
    }

    public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email)
     {
     try {
     new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(email, true);
     } catch (javax.mail.internet.AddressException e) {
     return false;
     }
     return true;
     }



    public static  Session getSession() {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
    }


    public static void SMTPSending(String from, String to, String subject, String content, String host) throws MessagingException
    {


          // Get system properties
           Properties properties = System.getProperties();  

          // Setup mail server
           properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  

          // Get the default Session object.

          // Create a default MimeMessage object.
           MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(getSession());  

          // Set the RFC 822 "From" header field using the
           // value of the InternetAddress.getLocalAddress method.
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 

          // Add the given addresses to the specified recipient type.
           message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

          // Set the "Subject" header field.
           message.setSubject(subject);  

          // Sets the given String as this part's content,
           // with a MIME type of "text/plain".
           message.setText(content,"UTF-8", "html");


          // Send message
           Transport.send(message);


    }



   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        String value1=text1.getText();
        String value2=text2.getText();
        String value3=text3.getText();
        System.out.println(value3);


    String value4 = "To approve this " + "proposal" + ": " +
        "<a href=\"mailto:"+
        "dealapproval@domain.com" + "?subject=" +
        "Proposal" + " " +
        "55544 -Andreea Deal(55544)(V.A)AP lavi test"+
        " for Approval number " + "10700" + "." +
        " For information only." + "\">" + 
        "dealapproval@domain.com" + "</a><br>";



        //String value4 = "www.google.com";
        value3 = value3+":  "+value4;
        boolean valid = isValidEmailAddress(value1);

        if (valid == true) {
             try {

            SMTPSending("andreeav@domain.com", value1, value2, value3,"mydomain");
            } catch (MessagingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             Popup page =new Popup();
            //set frame size
            page.setSize(200, 100);

             //center frame on screen
             page.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            page.setVisible(true);


       // page.dispose();
    }
        else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid e-mail address!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```

---

```
 class LoginDemo
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        try
        {

       Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       int height = screenSize.height;
       int width = screenSize.width;

        Login frame=new Login();
        //set frame size
        frame.setSize(width/2, height/2+200);

         //center frame on screen
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }
    catch(Exception e)
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());}
    }
}
```

---

```
//NextPage.java

import javax.swing.*;

class NextPage extends JFrame
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    NextPage()
    {
       setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       setTitle("Sending E-mails");
       setSize(400, 400);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please check if your password sent is correct and also add this property and check   
<prop key=”mail.smtp.starttls.enable”>true</prop>.

Comment: You should only post the relevant code, much of what you posted here is probably irrelevant gui code, that has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code that I used to send emails via my Gmail account, in my JSP academic project:

```
package my_util;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Mail
{
    private String  d_email = "myemailid@gmail.com",
                    d_password = "mypassword",
                    d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    d_port  = "465";


    public boolean sendMail(String strTo, String strSubject, String strBody){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        try
        {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(strBody);
            msg.setSubject(strSubject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(strTo));
            msg.saveChanges();

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(d_host, d_email, d_password);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I hope it might help you. :)